# Can the antlr4 parser see matching opening and closing text pattern?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm matching user-defined HTML-template tags that look like this (simplified):

```
{% label %} ... {% endlabel %}
```

The "label" is an alphanumeric value that a user can define himself, e.g.:

```
{% mytag %}<div>...</div>{% endmytag %}
```

Is there a way to tell the parser that the `LABEL` start tag text has to match with the `ENDLABEL` end tag text?  In other words, I want this to be invalid:

```
{% mytag %}<div>...</div>{% endnotmatchingtag %}
```

My lexer looks like this:

```
LABEL :                 ALPHA (ALPHA|DIGIT|UNDERSCORE)* ;
fragment UNDERSCORE:    '_' ;
fragment ALPHA:         [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT:         [0-9] ;

END :                   'end'
ENDLABEL :              END LABEL
TAGSTART :              '{%'
TAGEND :                '%}'

WS :                    [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

And the parser rule looks similar to this:

```
customtag: TAGSTART LABEL TAGEND block TAGSTART ENDLABEL TAGEND;
```

(and a block matches text or other tags recursively)

Right now I'm checking for a match in the listener, but I was hoping I could do it in the parser.   Is there any way to ensure that `ENDLABEL` is equal to `'end'` + `LABEL` at the parser level in Antlr4?

... and is it possible to do it if I weren't prepending 'end' in the lexer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two additional lexer rules

```
EndTag : TAGSTART ENDLABEL TAGEND;
StartTag : TAGSTART LABEL TAGEND;
```

Make sure that the token ENDLABEL is not subsumed by LABEL (yet LABEL matches the same text, but is preferred because it is first in the grammar!)

Use the new tokens in your grammar, similar as you did:

```
taggedElement : StartTag othernodes EndTag;
```

and insert a semantic predicate

```
taggedElement : StartTag othernodes EndTag {matches($StartTag.text,$EndTag.text)};
```

where `matches` is true if the tags are matching.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't want to modify the lexer in my particular case, but your answer led me to be able to do it in the parser as a semantic predicate.  I gave LABEL and ENDLABEL the names startlabel and endlabel and appended this C# to my parser rule:  `{ _localctx.endlabel().GetText().Equals("end" + _localctx.startlabel().GetText()) }?;`

Comment: @mikebridge Did you put the semantic predicate on the left of the rule? When I did this, I can't get the text of the `startlabel` and `endlabel`.

Answer (score 0):

A parser deals with syntax at the grammar level. What you are requesting can not be expressed in a Context Free Grammar (CFG), which suggests to me that you are not capable of solving this at the parser level.

In your schenario, I would create a visitor which enforces your semantics.
ANTLR 4 can generate abstract and base visitors for you, which you can then extend.